# Call established but no audio on both ends in sipml5

Tags: call, sipml5

I tried to call on sipml5 through 2 browsers. Even though the call has been initiated, we can't listen anything from another side. How to tackle this issue?

By the way, the browsers that I have used are;

1. Chrome (version 42)-can place call, but can't listen
2. Firefox-can place call but can't listen
3. Chromium-can't even place call

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough specific context in the description of the problem, I'm afraid, but you might want to check if the `<audio>` element associated with the call (the one whose reference was assigned to the session configuration property `audio_remote`) has the `autoplay` attribute set. Alternatively, you could call `play()` on the media element once the call has been established and incoming audio has been received.